# How to use a class with a constructor in another class?

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor

New in c++, I would like to use an class with a constructor in another class and use its methods globally.

**MyMachine** class calls **MyComponent** class. It works if MyComponent has no constructor, but I don't find how to call it with a constructor.

Working:

```
#include <iostream>

/*********************************************
* MyComponent
*********************************************/

// MyComponent.h
class MyComponent
{
  public:
    int _id;
    MyComponent();
    int getId();
};

// MyComponent.cpp
MyComponent::MyComponent()
{

}

int MyComponent::getId()
{
  return _id;
}

/*********************************************
* MyMachine
*********************************************/

// MyMachine.h
class MyMachine
{
  private:
    MyComponent component;
  public:
    MyMachine();
    void printComponentInfo();
};

MyMachine::MyMachine()
{
  component._id = 123456;
}

void MyMachine::printComponentInfo()
{
  int id = component.getId();
  std::cout << id << "\n";
}

/*********************************************
* Main
*********************************************/

int main()
{
  MyMachine machine;
  machine.printComponentInfo();

return 0;
}
```

Displays **123456**

But with the constructor, it is not working:

```
#include <iostream>

/*********************************************
* MyComponent
*********************************************/

// MyComponent.h
class MyComponent
{
  public:
    int _id;
    MyComponent(int id);
    int getId();
};

// MyComponent.cpp
MyComponent::MyComponent(int id)
{
    _id = id;
}

int MyComponent::getId()
{
  return _id;
}

/*********************************************
* MyMachine
*********************************************/

// MyMachine.h
class MyMachine
{
  private:
    MyComponent component(int id);
  public:
    MyMachine();
    void printComponentInfo();
};

MyMachine::MyMachine()
{
  component._id = 123456;
}

void MyMachine::printComponentInfo()
{
  int id = component.getId();
  std::cout << id << "\n";
}

/*********************************************
* Main
*********************************************/

int main()
{
  MyMachine machine;
  machine.printComponentInfo();

return 0;
}
```

An error is thrown

> all.cpp: In constructor ‘MyMachine::MyMachine()’: all.cpp:43:7: error:
>   invalid use of member function ‘MyComponent MyMachine::component(int)’
>   (did you forget the ‘()’ ?)
>          component._id = 123456;
>          ^~~~~~~~~ all.cpp: In member function ‘void MyMachine::printComponentInfo()’: all.cpp:48:16: error: invalid use of
>   member function ‘MyComponent MyMachine::component(int)’ (did you
>   forget the ‘()’ ?)
>          int id = component.getId();

Comment: Use the [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) to call parametric constructor

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 mistakes:

- missing default constructor for `MyComponent` class:

```cpp
MyComponent() : _id(0) {}
```

- wrong declaration of a private data member in `MyMachine` class:

```cpp
class MyMachine {
private:
    MyComponent component;
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you it works.
I just wondering how I can call MyComponent() constructor with a chosen int parameter in MyMachine. Is this possible?

Comment: @Phoax of course it is possible. You can have `MyMachine` constructor like this `MyMachine::MyMachine() : component(1) {}`. Here `MyComponent` constructor is called. If the answer helped you, please accept it.

Comment: @Phoax or you could even do `MyMachine::MyMachine(int id) : component(id) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

I think that your issue is with understanding ***when*** the constructor is being called.

When you construct a new object of `MyMachine`, the code first initializes all of `MyMachine`'s members **before** getting into the body of the constructor function. You can initialize the members on your own in the *initializer list* before getting into the ctor body:

```
MyMachine::MyMachine(int id) :
    _id(id)
{
}
```

In fact, this is a more efficent way to handle initialization, since all members **must** be initialized before the ctor body, therefore, in the previous state, the code will:

1. Initialize `_id` using its no-argument ctor.
2. Put the value `id` into MyComponent.

When you use the initializer list, there is only ***one*** step in the initialization, which is more efficient (especially in much more complex types!).